# How to check if string appears in worksheet *twice* Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check if a certain string appears on a given sheet twice. So far, I'm only able to check if the string appears once:

```
For Each curr In wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    If InStr(1, curr.Value, searchString) > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("searchString appears once")
    End If
Next
```

How do I check the UsedRange to see if the value appears twice? This needs to be a macro (so far I've found formulas that do this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(1).UsedRange, "*" & searchString & "*") > 1 Then 
    MsgBox searchString & " appears more than once"
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Set a flag when you find the first match, then check to see if the flag is set:

```
Dim first As Boolean
For Each curr In wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    If InStr(1, curr.Value, searchString) > 0 Then
        If first Then MsgBox ("searchString appears twice")
        first = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How would I use this to see if the value appears twice?

Comment: @studiis - Run it?

Comment: I think your code just checks if the value appears once
All you did was add a flag to my code

Comment: @studiis - No, it only displays the `MsgBox` if the flag is *set* and the flag only gets set when it finds the first match.

Comment: @studiis run it, it does what you want.  a msgbox will come up when it hits the second instance not the first.